# Best approach for music visualization/interaction app

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics

I'm am an experienced flash developer who's been learning objective-c for the last 5 months.

I am beginning the development of an app previously prototyped in Flash and I'm trying to guess what could be the best approach to port it to iOS.

My app is kind of a music game. It consists of some dynamic graphics (circles growing and rotating), with typography also changing and rotating. Everything moves in sync with music. And at the same time the user can interact with the app (moving and rotating things)  and some sounds will change depending on his actions.

Graphics can't be bitmaps because they get redrawn every frame.

This was easy to develop with Flash due to its management of vector graphics. But I'm not sure what would be the best way to do it in objective-c.

My options, I guess are things like: Core Graphics, OpenGL, maybe Cocos2D (not sure if that would be to kill a flea with a sledgehammer). Or even things like OpenFrameworks or Cinder, but I rather use objective-c other than c++.

Any hint on where to look at will be appreciated.

**EDIT**: 
I can't really put a real screenshot due to confidentiality issues. But it is something similar to this
[image: circle graphics]

But it will be interactive and sections would change size and disappear depending on the music and user interaction.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or a mockup to share as an example?

Comment: I can't do it with a real screenshot, but I put another one I think it clarifies it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which graphics library should you use? The answer is going to depend a lot on what you know or could learn. OpenGL will use hardware acceleration, so it's probably fastest. But OpenGL doesn't have built-in functions for drawing arc segments or any curves or text at all, so you'd probably have to do it yourself. Also, OpenGL is notoriously difficult to learn.

Core Graphics has many cool methods for drawing vector graphics (rectangles, arcs, general paths, etc.), but might be slower than you want, depending on what you're trying to do. Without having code to actually run it's hard to say.

It looks like Cocos2D is built on OpenGL and is made to be simple. I see lots of mention of sprites on their website, but nothing about vector graphics. (I've never used it, so it could be there and I'm just not seeing it.)

If I were in your position, I'd look into cocos2d and see if it does vector graphics at all. If not, I might give Core Graphics a try and see what performance was like. I know OpenGL can do what you want, but it can be difficult to learn, so I'd probably do that last.

Comment: Thanks, that's more or less what I thought. I do have a little experience with OpenGL, but I think it'll be hard to learn what I'm missing for this. I'll begin with cocos2d. I'm concern about typography most. It'll be great to hear from someone who had done something similar.